# Liquid Custom Tag: Block tag with optional closing tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, liquid

Is it possible to create a custom Liquid::Block tag that has an *optional* closing tag?

For example:

```
{% mytag 'parameter' %}
    <!-- ...Do something... -->
{% endmytag %}
```

or:

```
{% mytag 'parameter' %} <!-- Do something else -->
```

The closest thing to a pre-existing example I could find was the built-in "if" tag which can *sometimes* have an optional "else" or "elsif" tag within it. This is achieved by overriding the "unknown_tag" method in the class and handling the "else" and "elsif" tags through there. Basically, if no closing tag is found, I simply need to render some content inline at the location of the custom tag in the template. Otherwise, I need to get the contents of the block and replace it with different content.

Answer (score 0):

So, I think I've solved this. I'm sure there's probably a better way using some of the built-in, undocumented Liquid API's. But, this appears to at least work for my use case:

```
class MyTag < Liquid::Block
  def initialize(tag_name, markup, tokens)
    super

    # Other init code here...
  end

  def parse(tokens)
    @has_closing_tag = has_closing_tag?(tokens)

    super(tokens) if @has_closing_tag
  end

  def render(context)
    if @has_closing_tag
      # Handle normal "block" case here...
    else
      # Handle special "tag" case here...
    end
  end

  private
    def has_closing_tag?(tokens)
      stack = []

      tokens.each do |token|
        next unless token.match(Liquid::TagStart, 0)

        tag_name = FullToken.match(token)[1]

        stack.push(block_name) if tag_name == block_name

        if tag_name == block_delimiter
          return true if stack.size == 0

          stack.pop
        end
      end

      false
    end
end
```